# ¿Como puedo crear dos lista con restricción a partir de una con números aleatorios en python?

Tags: python, lista

me asignaron estas dos preguntas para realizarlas en python

• Haga una lista del largo que usted quiera, en donde todos los elementos de la lista tienen que ser números aleatorios (con decimales) entre 1 y el largo de la lista.

– REQUISITO: la lista tiene que ser al menos de 100 elementos.

• Genere dos listas, una que guarde los números mayores que 50 y otra que almacene los números menores que 50 de la lista que acaba de generar en la sección anterior.

Intente lo siguiente en la primera parte

```
import random

desde = 1
hasta = 150
cantidad = 100

numeros = [random.uniform(desde,hasta) for x in range(cantidad)]

print(numeros)
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!
Esta escrito exactamente cómo me lo mandaron!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas he creado dos listas y al lanzarme los aleatorios con uniform() para que los de con decimales, simplemente con un condicional los he asignado a la lista con mayores de 50 o menores de 50.

```
import random
lista_menores=[]
lista_mayores=[]
for i in range (1,101):
  x=random.uniform(1,150)
  if x>0 and x<50:
    lista_menores.append(round(x,2)) 
  else:   
    lista_mayores.append(round(x,2))

print(f'La lista con numeros menores de 50--->{lista_menores}')
print(f'La lista con los numeros mayores de 50--->{lista_mayores}'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Para la parte uno de crear la lista estaría bien lo que hice? Porque a partir de esa lista generada hay que crear las otras dos con las restricciones

Comment: @Friner si esta bien lo ue has hecho

Comment: Indenta bien tu código, tal y como lo pones en tu respuesta fallará ;)

Comment: Como que va a fallar? si en el comentario de arriba dijiste que estaba bien? Si esta malo no me podrias dar le codigo bueno? Que no entiendo mucho de pyhton :(

Comment: @Friner lo tuyo esta bien, solo le decía a Javier que indente bien su código, pero creo que no lo hará, asi que editaré su publicación

Comment: También pude arreglar el comentario de Javier pero el problema es que me da numeros distintos a los que el codigo me tira en la primera parte. No se si se entiende :( Con el codigo que escribí me da ciertos numeros y esos son los que necesito agrupar siendo mayor o menor a 50. Pero ese codigo me tira otros numeros aleatorios.

Comment: @Friner los números son aleatorios y siempre cambiarán con cada ejecución. Sería bueno que [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/489767/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo más detalles y tal vez te pueda dar una mejor respuesta

Comment: La pregunta la escribí tal cual me la dió mi profesor, pero no existe forma de hacer la segunda pregunta con los números de la primera? Porque eso es lo que se me pide. La dos nuevas listas se tienen que resolver con la lista hecha en la pregunta 1. Eso dice especificamente el enunciado

Comment: @Friner si se puede solo añade en  código esta respuesta y cambia el `range (1,101)` por `numeros` y todo solucionado :D. Avisame si te funciona

Comment: Cambie lo que dijo y sigue sin funcionar :( me da otros numeros aleatorios

Comment: @Friner ya te dije que los números no serán los mismos, cambian con cada ejecución. La única forma de comprobar que sea correcto es que en la lista `lista_menores` se encuentren los números menores y en `lista_mayores` los mayores

Comment: Es que según yo eso es lo que pide, dice el enunciado que se generen dos listas que guarden los numero mayores y menores de la lista hecha en la 1.

Comment: Creo que ahí pude hacerlo :) 
lista_menores=[numeros]
lista_mayores=[numeros]
for i in numeros:
  x=random.uniform(1,150)
  if x>0 and x<50:
    lista_menores.append(round(x,2)) 
  else:   
    lista_mayores.append(round(x,2))

print(f'La lista con numeros menores de 50--->{lista_menores}')
print(f'La lista con los numeros mayores de 50--->{lista_mayores}'

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ahora le hice un rounded array a la lista tanto a la pregunta 1 como a la 2 y me quedo súper bien! Te lo agradezco un montón :)

Comment: Buenas, no estaba hasta ahora, bueno gracias Christian, me fijaré bien. Un saludo.